# Cannot get Custom Theme.scss file Angular material 2

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, angular-material

I have created a custom theme(Material 2) for my angular 4.x app. I have imported it in my Css file but getting error `cannot get Theme.scss`

Theme.scss

```
@import '../node_modules/@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

$my-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-blue-grey);
$my-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, 500, 900, A100);
$my-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-deep-orange);

$my-app-theme: mat-light-theme($my-app-primary, $my-app-accent, $my-app-warn);

@include angular-material-theme($my-app-theme);

.alternate-theme {
  $alternate-primary: mat-palette($mat-light-blue);
  $alternate-accent:  mat-palette($mat-yellow, 400);

  $alternate-theme: mat-light-theme($alternate-primary, $alternate-accent);

  @include angular-material-theme($alternate-theme);
  }
```

How I imported in CSS file

```
@import "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/Theme.scss";
```

I have saved my custom theme inside prebuilt themes folder .The problem is with custom themes only if I import prebuilt css theme file it's working

[image]

Comment: You can't import scss files in css! If you're using angular-cli, simply put `theme.scss` into `styles` object in `angular-cli.json`.

Comment: But I am not using Angular cli